# Loading Multiple Sheets in QlikView

Tags: excel, scripting, qlikview

I have been working on creating a QlikView dashboard for my senior management to use, the current build uses a simple AccessDB back-end to source all tables loaded into the dashboard. However, due to our system limitations, if we'd like to host the dashboard on our intranet the back-end has to be switched to Excel.

Instead of creating multiple Excel files to load them up separately, I was thinking of connecting all my tables directly into Excel with multiple sheets representing multiple tables. By default when you load Excel into QV it only reads the first sheet, is there a way to get it to read all sheets in that Excel file?

Let me know your thoughts.

Regards,
Yasir

Comment: of course. just use the table load wizard..it lets you choose sheets. you also have the sheet name in the script syntax after the "FROM some file.xls (ooxml, embedded labels, table is [anysheetyouwant])"

Answer (score 0):

I saw the solution to this a few days ago. But I am not sure where is the post anymore or whether it works. Regardless, here is what I remember:

Here is the usual one:
(biff, no labels, table is [Table$])

But if you want to load all sheets,
(biff, no labels)
^In order to do this, make sure all sheets are in the same format/ table.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set vFileName, vStartIndex, vEndIndex

```
// create a dummy table. it will be used in first concatenation 

    Excel:
    Load * Inline
         [DummyFiled];

// loop all your sheets and build Excel table 

    FOR index = vStartIndex TO vEndIndex
         concatenate(Excel)
         LOAD
              *
         FROM [$(vFileName).xlsx]
         (ooxml, embedded labels, table is [Page $(index)]);
    NEXT index;
```